# C++ replacing part of string with a variable double

Tags: c++, string

**I've found that the errors are:**

**_Mycont CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated and _Mynextiter CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated but i still dont know how to fix**

This program uses the string prompt and replaces "{0}" with 5.651 and "{1}" with 3.427 and it works fine.

However, when I change the string to "{0:c}" and "{1:c}" to replace the substring and format them as currency, "{0:f}" and "{1:f}" to replace the substring and format them as fixed point notation, "{0:e}" and "{1:e}" to replace the substring and format them as scientific notation, "{0:i}" and "{1:i}" to replace the substring and round to an integer, they all work independently.

But when I try and put them into cases like if("{0}"), else if("{0:c}") it only works if I am looking for "{0}" anything else it doesn't work. I get a debug error. How do I fix this, what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
void main()
{
    write("The number {0} is greater than {1}.\n", 5.651, 3.427);
}

void write(string prompt, ...)
{
    double small, large, temp;

    va_list arguments;
    va_start(arguments, prompt);

    large = va_arg(arguments, double);
    small = va_arg(arguments, double);
    if(small > large)
    {
        temp = large;
        large = small;
        small = temp;
    }

    if(prompt.find("{0}"))
    {
        ostringstream a;
        a << large;
        string arg1 = a.str();
        ostringstream s;
        s << small;
        string arg2 = s.str();

        size_t pos = prompt.find("{0}");
        prompt = prompt.replace(pos, 3, arg1);
        size_t pos2 = prompt.find("{1}");
        prompt = prompt.replace(pos2, 3, arg2);
    }

    else if(prompt.find("{0:c}"))
    { 
        ostringstream a;
        a << large;
        string arg1 = "$" + a.str();
        ostringstream s;
        s << small;
        string arg2 = "$" + s.str();

        size_t pos = prompt.find("{0:c}");
        prompt = prompt.replace(pos, 5, arg1);
        size_t pos2 = prompt.find("{1:c}");
        prompt = prompt.replace(pos2, 5, arg2);
    }

    else if(prompt.find("{0:e}"))
    { 
        ostringstream a;
        a << scientific << large;
        string arg1 = a.str();
        ostringstream s;
        s << scientific << small;
        string arg2 = s.str();

        size_t pos = prompt.find("{0:e}");
        prompt = prompt.replace(pos, 5, arg1);
        size_t pos2 = prompt.find("{1:e}");
        prompt = prompt.replace(pos2, 5, arg2);
    }

    else if(prompt.find("{0:f}"))
    { 
        ostringstream a;
        a << fixed << setprecision(6) << large;
        string arg1 = a.str();
        ostringstream s;
        s << fixed << setprecision(6) << small;
        string arg2 = s.str();

       size_t pos = prompt.find("{0:f}");
       prompt = prompt.replace(pos, 5, arg1);
       size_t pos2 = prompt.find("{1:f}");
       prompt = prompt.replace(pos2, 5, arg2);
    }

    else if(prompt.find("{0:i}"))
    { 
        ostringstream a;
        a << (int)large;
        string arg1 = a.str();
        ostringstream s;
        s << (int)small;
        string arg2 = s.str();

        size_t pos = prompt.find("{0:i}");
        prompt = prompt.replace(pos, 5, arg1);
        size_t pos2 = prompt.find("{1:i}");
        prompt = prompt.replace(pos2, 5, arg2);
    }

    cout << prompt;
    cout << endl;

    va_end(arguments);
}
```

Comment: the program works the way it is now but in main if i change, write("The number {0} is greater than {1}.\n", 5.651, 3.427); to, write("The number {0:c} is greater than {1:c}.\n", 5.651, 3.427); for example, the program doesnt work

Comment: Anyone? Im not sure what is wrong with my question.

Comment: You didn't read the documentation for the functions that you used. You also did not narrow down your problem to a tiny testcase that would have revealed the issue to you (i.e. you didn't debug).

Comment: i actually did debug and came up with the same answer as the guy below me

Comment: So then why did you need to ask? That's why you got downvotes!

Comment: because i was having trouble figuring out the issue, what is so difficult to understand, im new at programming and needed help so i asked.

Comment: Yet as you just said, you _did_ debug and you found the answer yourself. Contradiction detected!!

Comment: yes i did after struggling for hours lol so i decided to ask, after taking a break and coming back i was able to find it on my own. no harm in asking for help especially when your new,

Comment: What I'm trying to teach you is that you should take the break and come back and try again, _before_ resorting to asking for help! :) That you figured this out on your own is proof that you did not need to ask. Hopefully now, given this success, you'll have the confidence to do that next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression in your "**if**" condition is not doing what you think it is doing.  See [documentation for std::string find function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/)

> **Return Value**
>
> The position of the first character of the first match. If no matches were found, the function returns string::npos.

So this

```
if(prompt.find("{0}"))
```

Should be

```
if(prompt.find("{0}") != string::npos)
```

If the string literal you look for with **find** is not found, **find** returns **string::npos** which is not equal to zero, so the **if** evaluates to **true**, which is not what you want.  Likewise for all the other **if** conditions with **find**.

Comment: Yes, i did some debugging and ended up coming to this same conclusion. thanks anyway

Comment: @JoaoDias glad you figured it out on your own, welcome to programming and welcome to stackoverflow